# Detect F key press after holding right mouse button

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a script that detects `Right Mouse Click` being held for at least 1.5 seconds and then the `F` key being pressed down while `Right Mouse Click` is still being held.

I tried the following:

```
Loop
{
Send, {F Down}
Sleep 2000
Send, {F Up}
sleep 1500
}
return

^F::Pause
```

I realized this is only a timer and does not detect which keys were pressed. How do I write a script that achieves functionality described above?

Comment: Hmm. Not too unclear for me, I guess.  What OP wants (from orig text) is to press and hold the right mouse button for at least 1.5 seconds, and then, if OP is still holding the right mouse button while the "F" key is pressed down, something happens.  It doesn't matter what, the question is how to detect a keypress (whether F is pressed) during a correct interval (gt 1.5 seconds) while a mouse button is clicked.  I could answer this, probably, b/c I have seen code posted here that purports to track the key presses that happen _after_ a hotkey (e.g., right mouse down) is triggered.

Comment: never mind , PGilm ,, 

roman,He answered Me, thx

Comment: Glad it worked out @diana_adam. I only put my comment because several folks had **marked your question as unclear** and not satisfying the posting requirements (and the question was on hold, and **there was no way to leave an answer**).  So, I knew what you wanted (and would have answered, too, obviously, except the overeager moderators prevented me from doing so) and figured a comment might get them to remove the "hold."  And I guess it worked.  So where's my love? (upvote my comments, pls, thx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loop
 {
 Key := GetKeyState("rbutton")

 while(Key = 0)
  {
  Key := GetKeyState("rbutton")
  sleep,100
  }

 while(Key = 1)
  {
  sleep,100
  loopnmb := A_Index
  if(loopnmb = 8) ;;this number changes the length rbutton has to be pressed before F key activates 
   {
   Key := GetKeyState("rbutton")  
   while(Key = 1)
    {   
    Send, {F Down}
    Key := GetKeyState("rbutton")
    if(Key = 0) 
     {
     Send, {F Up}
     break
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Timer is a little bit off so play around with it.